# Project <name> could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created

Tags: visual-studio, c#, visual-studio-2015

### Problem

I've got a new machine and installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. However, when I go to create a new C# Windows Forms project, I get this error:

[image: Project could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.]

### What I've Tried

- Add/Remove Programs - Repair Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
- Run VS 2015 Developer Command Prompt as admin, then `devenv /resetsettings`
- Complete uninstall of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, then reinstall
- Using VB.NET instead of C#, basically the same error, but for Visual Basic 2015

### What Does Work

- Projects created under .NET Core

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the project from solution then Undo the solution pending changes & get latest